# redirect to action from global action filter .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, custom-action-filter

In my .net core project, I need to show a maintenance page when we do deployment. so, I have decided to write an action filter and registered globally and set the config value to check when maintenance is on, I will redirect to my maintenance page. The problem is that redirection is happening, but the web page keeps reloading. Please find below code

**MyActionFilterAttribute.cs**

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute {
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public OfflineActionFilterAttribute(IConfiguration config) {
        _config = config;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext == null) return;

        if (bool.Parse(_config.GetSection("Maintenance:Mode").Value) && filterContext.HttpContext ? .Request ? .Path.Value != "/Maintenance") {
            // Some logic goes here to satisfy conditions then only the below code should be executed.
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                controller = "Maintenance",
                action = "Index"
            }));

        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

In Configure Method,

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
         {
              options.Filters.Add(new OfflineActionFilterAttribute(_configuration));
         });
```

**Maintenance Controller**

```
 public class MaintenanceController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The url https://localhost:XXXXX/Maintenance keeps loading.

The question is:

1. How can I stop redirecting too many times issue. [Please Note: I have checked other stack overflow questions. There it suggests to check specific controller, that does not help in my case].
2. Is there any other approach to be considered? I have a thought of using Middleware, we can send the response, but I am not sure how I redirect to my .net razor page with dynamic content.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Check this actionfilter
https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web.Framework/Mvc/Filters/CheckAccessClosedStoreAttribute.cs

Comment: @sina_Islam, Thanks for the update. could you please tell me how that is solving my problem. Sorry, I am not able to understand what you are inferring. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use custom middleware. You could directly set the response context path after you checked the config.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if ("condition")
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Maintenance/Index");
                return;
            }
            else
            {   
                // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
                await next();
            }
           
   
        });
```

---

Update:

Startup.cs Configure method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToNonWww());

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //app.UseHsts();

        }

        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSession();   
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (Condition && context.Request.Path != "/error/404")
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/error/404");
                return;
            }
            else
            {                // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline

                await next();
            }


        });


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update @Brando. Apologies for the late update. I will apply this and let you know.

Comment: You should also add another condition inside  if ("condition") to check the path is  /Maintenance/Index and not redirect again and again .

Comment: I tried like below and redirection keeps happening.
 `public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
 {
    if(condition && context.Request.Path != "/Maintenance")
    {                          
           context.Response.Redirect("/Maintenance");
           return;
    }
    await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Could you please tell me where you add this invoke middleware? What's the  ` if(condition && context.Request.Path != "/Maintenance") `'s result?  I suggest you could directly write a custom middleware inside the startup.cs file. Details, you could refer to my update answer.

Comment: I have created a new middleware file and called from configure. will try your suggestions and let you know. Thanks.